# Angular custom form validation across inputs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have 2 fields. Im trying to validate that field 2 is not the same as field1. I used a directive

It works, but my question is around enhancing it a bit. It only works when typing data into field 2. It does not work when changing data in field 1. So in other words, if field 1 is "Babbalas" and you type "Babbalas" into field 2 it correctly displays my validation message. If you change field 2 it takes the validation away correctly (because now the fields arent the same). But, if you go and change field 1 it doesnt change the validation message on field 2, is there a way to achieve this.

I have a Plunker with what i did

http://plnkr.co/edit/OcwyoXwjcbVmTYuKN5hT?p=preview

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="doSomething()">
       <div>
           <input type="text" name="item1" ng-model="data.item1" required/>
         <span class="invalid" ng-show="myForm.item1.$error.required">required</span>
         <br/>  
       </div>
       <div>
           <input type="text" name="item2" ng-model="data.item2" validate-item2 required/>
         <span class="invalid" ng-show="myForm.item2.$error.validateItem2">
            Cannot be the same as item1</span>
         <span class="invalid" ng-show="myForm.item2.$error.required">required</span>
         <br/>  
       </div>
       <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

and my js file

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.doSomething = function () { 
    alert('Submitted!');
  }
});

app.directive('validateItem2', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
           ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                var valid = value != scope.data.item1;
                ngModel.$setValidity('validateItem2', valid);
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            });
      }
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass item1 as scope parameter to the directive and watch its value there. And in the watch method, you can validate id both the items have same value or not.